# Do I always have to declare a variable in angular2 to get changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular-pipe

I have the following code:

**This is the HTML view:**

```
<button type="button" (click)="filterIt('male')">Filter male gender</button>
     <table>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let item of array;let i=index">
       <tr class="border-bottom" *ngIf="item.condition==condition_var">
         <td>{{i+1}}</td>
         <td>{{item.condition}}</td>
       </tr>
     </ng-container>
</table>
```

**This is the typescript file** (.ts):

```
  condition_var:string;
   filterIt(value){
     this.condition_var=value;
  }
```

**NOTE:** the *array* variable is already populated. (array of objects:
 `[{}]`)

My question is: Is it a practice in angular2 to always declare variables and to work with them in expressions, ngIf, ngFor etc. Or can I use a better way rather than populating my class with too many variables which doesn't look good.

To be more specific, is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: Look at pipe, rather than looping thought whole array filter it beforehand.

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking

Comment: I've looked at pipes and am going to make a custom one... Will post my answer when done

Comment: Do you _really_ filter with a button?

Comment: @msanford Is there a problem with doing that? I'm just experimenting..

Comment: you dont really have to declare, if you want to avoid populating your class with too many variables as you say.

Comment: @masterach Nope! Just wondering because normally you'd have a drop-down and you could pass that variable. Experimentation is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a better (more idiomatic) way to do this: [use a `@Pipe`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-globally-available-custom-pipe-in-angular-2).

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: any, condition: any): any {
    return values.filter(item => item.condition === condition);
  }
}
```

Implement with:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array | filter:condition">
```

And set the `condition` however you like. Note that filters can accept more than one positional parameter, separated by colons.

Remember to add the pipe to whichever `@NgModule`s you use the pipe in:

```
import { FilterPipe } from 'pipes/fitler.pipe.ts';

@NgModule({
  declaractions: [
    FilterPipe
  ],
  // ...
})
```

*And if* the `@NgModule` in question is a lazy-loaded "shared" module, don't forget to re-export it:

```
@NgModule({
      declaractions: [
        FilterPipe
      ],
      exports: [
        FilterPipe
      ],
      // ...
    })
```

This answer is currently valid as of angular `4.3.6`.

Comment: My pleasure. We use filter pipes extensively in our own application. They are very powerful and obviate the need to repeat custom filtering code which, I agree with you, clutters the @Components.

Comment: is the first parameter of transform always an array which we have to pass?

Comment: @masterach No, the first parameter to `PipeTransform` is whatever value you want to act on. In your case, it will be an array (since you want to filter it) but `PipeTransform` is generic (I wrote a pipe to create plurals, which is just a single string). The rest of the function definition is up to you. The interface signature defined in Angular (in `pipe_transform.d.ts`) is `transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any;`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a getter inside your component class which filters the array you're looping over. Like this:

```
public myArray: any[] = [];
public myCondition: string | null = null;

public get myFilteredArray() {
  return this.myArray.filter(item => item.condition === this.myCondition);
}
```

And in your template just use the filteredArray:

```
<table>
  <tr class="border-bottom" *ngFor="let item of myFilteredArray;let i=index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.condition}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or you could build a pipe for it:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'myFilterPipe' })
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any[], condition: string | null): any[] {
    if(!Array.isArray(value)) return [];
    return value.filter(item => item.condition === condition);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are filtering the data based on "male" string.

So you can directly use the following snippets:

```
*ngIf="item.condition=='male'"
```

don't need to make function, it will handle in **if block**,

Comment: yes, you can use your declared variable of ts file in your html. and yes ofCourse it is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it this way:

```
//YOUR COMPONENT .TS CODE
filterIt(parameter: String){
//filter this.array here using your parameter
}

//YOUR COMPONENT .HTML CODE
<button type="button" (click)="filterIt('male')">Filter male gender</button>
 <table>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of array;">
   <tr class="border-bottom">
     <td>{{i+1}}</td>
     <td>{{item.condition}}</td>
   </tr>
 </ng-container>
```

This is much cleaner and let's the logic happen in your.ts file while your web page only displays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach if you want to avoid declaring the variable in your class. Just initialize variable on button click:

```
<button type="button" (click)="condition = 'male'">Filter male gender</button>
<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of array;let i=index">
        <tr class="border-bottom" *ngIf="item.condition == condition">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.condition}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

You don't have to declare `condition`, `condition_var` or `filterIt()` method in your class in this way. Link to [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ksHhHaQoQo831QUsUWt6?p=preview).